# Web Scrape from <Article or <Span in Source

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

What about if it's not in a frame? I am working to gather some details from this site https://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/SMS/Carrier/621247/CarrierRegistration.aspx in which I am not able to pull the data.

I'm trying to pull the text in `<span class="dat">` items from the `<div id="regBox">` though not retrieving. Wanting Legal Name, Address, Miles Traveled and Email. As well the entire Vehicle Type Breakdown listed in separate cells within 1 cell.

Can this be done?

```
Sub ScrapeFMSCA(DOTNum)


Dim ie As Object
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieEle As Object

Dim k As Long
Dim s As Object
Dim P As String
Dim txt As String
Dim rng As Range, cname As String
Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
Dim elemCollection As Object, curHTMLRow As Object

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

k = 2

With ie
    .Visible = True

    URL = "https://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/SMS/Carrier/" & DOTNum & "/CarrierRegistration.aspx"
    Application.StatusBar = " Logging In "
    .Navigate URL

    Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop '** Wait til page loaded
    Do While ie.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop '** Wait til IE READY

    Set ieDoc = ie.Document
    Set NodeList = ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("article").getElementsByTagName("span").getElementsByClassName("dat")(1)
    MsgBox NodeList.span

    cTime = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")
    Do Until (ie.ReadyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy)
        If Now < cTime Then
            DoEvents
        Else
            GoTo Here1
        End If
    Loop

Here1:

    ie.Quit

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: can you provide an example of `DOTNum` so I can take a look at the HTML?

Comment: So your post is about getting a macro capale of fetching all of your required fields!!! If someone does that whole thing for you then what will be your try @Kevin Harris KreizK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this as shown below. This solution is written with your future looping over multiple DOTNums in mind. I have tested with a loop over 3 numbers and it works perfectly.

**Access method:**

I use XMLHTTP request as a much faster method of retrieval than launching IE.

**Registration Info:**

The registration info I get by applying a CSS class selector to target elements with class `.dat`. I then index into the `nodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` to retrieve the required elements.

**Vehicle type breakdown:**

The full vehicle type breakdown table I initially grab by index and tag with `.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)`.

The table has a slightly tricky layout. For example, the first column elements are actually `th` not `td` tagged. I get around this by first isolating the actual headers with a CSS descendant selector combination of `thead th`. This targets just the `th` elements in the table header. I then use the CSS OR operator within a CSS descendant selector combination to pull back the first column `th` elements or the remaining columns `td` tagged elements: `tbody tr th,td`. 
I use `mod 4` to determine whether it is first column or not and adjust the write out to a new row accordingly.

**Helpers (modular code is best practice):**

I have used a `GetLastRow` helper function to determine where to start writing out to as it looks like you will be deploying this in a loop eventually over different DOTnums. I use a class to hold the XMLHTTP object.

`WriteTable` does at is says. It writes out the table.

**dotNums:**

I read the dotNums in from a sheet called `DOTNumbers`. In my example, I use 3 numbers to grab info for `{529136,621247,2474795}`. The array `dotNums` is populated with these values from the sheet, and is looped over to provide the dotNum to be added into the Url.

---

**Example of the OR operator in the CSS query (sample):**

[image]

---

**Sample Output:**

[image]

---

### **VBA:**

**Class module clsHTTP:**

```
Option Explicit    
Private http As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
End Sub

Public Function GetString(ByVal url As String) As String
    Dim sResponse As String
    With http
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
        GetString = sResponse
    End With
End Function
```

**Standard module 1:**

```
Option Explicit    
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, headers1(), hTable As HTMLTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsDotNums As Worksheet, registrationinfo As Object, nextRow As Long
    Dim dotNums(), http As clsHTTP, url As String, i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set http = New clsHTTP
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDotNums = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DOTNumbers")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    dotNums = Application.Transpose(wsDotNums.Range("A1:A3").Value) '<== Change the range here to the single column range containing your dotNums.

    For i = LBound(dotNums) To UBound(dotNums)
        If Not IsEmpty(dotNums(i)) Then
            With html
                url = "https://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/SMS/Carrier/" & dotNums(i) & "/CarrierRegistration.aspx"
                html.body.innerHTML = http.GetString(url)
                Set registrationinfo = .querySelectorAll(".dat")
                Set hTable = .getElementsByTagName("table")(0)
            End With

            headers1 = Array("Legal Name", "Address", "Miles Traveled ", "Email")

            nextRow = IIf(GetLastRow(ws, 1) = 1, 1, GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 2)

            With ws
                .Cells(nextRow, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers1) + 1) = headers1
                .Cells(nextRow + 1, 1) = registrationinfo.item(0).innerText
                .Cells(nextRow + 1, 2) = registrationinfo.item(3).innerText
                .Cells(nextRow + 1, 3) = registrationinfo.item(7).innerText
                .Cells(nextRow + 1, 4) = registrationinfo.item(6).innerText
            End With

            WriteTable hTable, nextRow + 3, ws

        End If     
    Next      
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Sub WriteTable(ByVal hTable As HTMLTable, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim r As Long, c As Long, i As Long, headers As Object
    r = startRow
    With ws
        Set headers = hTable.querySelectorAll("thead th")
        For i = 0 To headers.Length - 1
            .Cells(r, i + 1) = headers.item(i).innerText
        Next

        Dim tableContents As Object
        Set tableContents = hTable.querySelectorAll("tbody tr th,td")

        For i = 0 To tableContents.Length - 1
            If i Mod 4 = 0 Then
                c = 1: r = r + 1
            Else
                c = c + 1
            End If
            .Cells(r, c) = tableContents.item(i).innerText
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 2):

You might think of giving a shot the following way as well. It should fetch you all your aforementioned fields. I tried to compact it within a single sub. However, If you have loops to carry on the script should not make a mess. I've used simple selectors within the script along with nested loops to get your job done. Hope this helps.

```
Sub FetchData()
    Const link As String = "https://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/SMS/Carrier/621247/CarrierRegistration.aspx"
    Dim Httpreq As New XMLHTTP60, Htmldoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim R&, I&, tR&, N&, C&

    With Httpreq
        .Open "GET", link, False
        .send
        Htmldoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    [A1:C1] = [{"Legal Name", "Address", "Miles Traveled"}]

    With Htmldoc.querySelectorAll("#regBox label,#regBox h3")
        For R = 0 To .Length - 1
            If .item(R).innerText Like "*Legal Name*" Then
                I = I + 1: Cells(I + 1, 1) = .item(R).NextSibling.innerText
            End If

            If .item(R).innerText Like "*Address*" Then
                Cells(I + 1, 2) = .item(R).NextSibling.innerText
            End If

            If .item(R).innerText Like "*Vehicle Miles Traveled*" Then
                Cells(I + 1, 3) = .item(R).NextSibling.innerText
            End If

            If .item(R).innerText Like "*Vehicle Type Breakdown*" Then
                With .item(R).NextSibling.Rows
                    For tR = 0 To .Length - 1
                        With .item(tR).Cells
                            For N = 0 To .Length - 1
                                C = C + 1: Cells(I + 2, C) = .item(N).innerText
                            Next N
                        End With
                        I = I + 1: C = 0
                    Next tR
                End With
            End If
        Next R
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Running the following macro, you will get your first three required fields:

```
Sub GetInformation()
    Const Url$ = "https://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/SMS/Carrier/621247/CarrierRegistration.aspx"
    Dim Http As New xmlhttp60, Html As New HTMLDocument, post As Object, I&

    With Http
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each post In Html.getElementsByTagName("label")
        If InStr(post.innerText, "Legal Name") > 0 Then
            I = I + 1: Cells(I, 1) = post.NextSibling.innerText
        End If

        If InStr(post.innerText, "Address") > 0 Then
            Cells(I, 2) = post.NextSibling.innerText
        End If

        If InStr(post.innerText, "Vehicle Miles Traveled") > 0 Then
            Cells(I, 3) = post.NextSibling.innerText
        End If
    Next post
End Sub
```

Reference to add:

```
Microsoft xml, v6.0
Microsoft Html Object Library
```

Comment: I was using a subroutine to search for the Motor Carrier (MC#) on  from https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/CompanySnapshot.aspx, then from here we'll get the DOTNum to proceed with this subroutine.  With all of your help I was able to have my list of MCNumbers (000000 to 999999) which will continuously pull updated dated from FMCSA's site (I like getting all the emails)